# openstack instance metadata

Tags: cloud, openstack

With Openstack Nova CLI I could set or get instance metadata with `nova meta set/get ...` but with the  openstack "all-in-one" CLI that option does not exist.

Is it possible to work with instance metadata with the openstack client?

PS: Someone with privileges to create tags could create `openstack` , `openstack-nova` and `openstack-cli` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just browsing through the available options, it looks like the `nova meta` actions may be available as `openstack server set`:

```
$ openstack help server set
usage: openstack server set [-h] [--name <new-name>] [--root-password]
                            [--property <key=value>] [--state <state>]
                            <server>

Set server properties

positional arguments:
  <server>              Server (name or ID)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --name <new-name>     New server name
  --root-password       Set new root password (interactive only)
  --property <key=value>
                        Property to add/change for this server (repeat option
                        to set multiple properties)
  --state <state>       New server state (valid value: active, error)
```

E.g., if I run:

```
openstack server set myserver --property foo=bar
```

And then run:

```
openstack server show myserver
```

I see:

```
[...]
| properties                           | foo='bar'                                                |
[...]
```

Comment: You're right! it seems that has been changed the concept from "metadata" to "property"